# How to solve definite integral in range of complex number, such as $ \int_{-1-i}^{1+i} (1) dx $?

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-numbers

Can definite integral be in range of complex number, like this?
$$ \int_{-1-i}^{1+i} (1) dx $$
Then what does this mean?

Do I have to define what path it is on and do special thing with it to make it work? Or it is just as nature as thing in the world of real number? If I want to approximate it with $\Sigma$, do I just need to define the step for it and it will work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex integration where the limits are complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792630/complex-integration-where-the-limits-are-complex-numbers)

Comment: well,it is actually,but the example in it is much much diffcult than the one I bringing on now,and I have no idea about how to actually doing it,so I just made this question that should be simple enough that can be a sign for anyone want to know more about it(which is also where I am now)

Comment: The _answer_ to the previous question also applies to your case -- and doesn't really give any details that are different because $(z^3-z)e^{z^2/2}$ is more complicated than $1$. The pertinent fact is that both functions are defined and analytic on all of $\mathbb C$, and in that particular case you can use the same "find an antiderivative" process you use would use for real integrals, just plugging in the complex endpoints.